# scrollview is not scrolling android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

when i ran the layout it took more space than the screen , i am trying to add ScrollView
but it just dosen't function .  i read every answer availiable but still it doesn't scroll.
anyone knows where is the problem?

here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_headLine_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#21410C"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/uers_pic_iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_smaller" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/uers_name_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:text="@string/fective_name"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_font" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_zone_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#557265"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/general_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                android:text="@string/my_zone"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_info_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/uers_bank_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="@string/bank"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_font" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bank_value_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="120,000"
                android:textColor="#66FF99"
                android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_font" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/invested_info_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/uers_invested_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="@string/invested"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_font" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/invested_value_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="80,000"
                android:textColor="#66FF99"
                android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_font" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/level_info_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/uers_level_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="@string/level"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_font" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/level_value_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="01"
                android:textColor="#66FF99"
                android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_font" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rank_info_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/uers_rank_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:text="@string/rank"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_font" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rank_value_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:text="Jounior"
                android:textColor="#66FF99"
                android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_font" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/uers_rank_tv"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:background="#B3B3B3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="3/10" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="21dip"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Dog" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                    android:text="Jounior" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_stuff_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#557265"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/general_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="@string/my_stuff"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/feedback_btn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dip"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                android:minWidth="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/all_bets" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/active_friends_btn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/feedback_btn"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="-7dip"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                android:minWidth="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/all_tournaments" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/notifications_btn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/active_friends_btn"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="-7dip"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                android:minWidth="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/notifications" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_friends_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
            android:background="#557265"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/general_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="@string/my_friends"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/feedback_btn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dip"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                android:minWidth="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/invite_friends" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/active_friends_btn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/feedback_btn"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="-7dip"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                android:minWidth="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/active_friends_list" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/general_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
            android:background="#557265"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/general_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="@string/general"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/feedback_btn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dip"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                android:minWidth="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/feedback" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/settings_btn"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/feedback_btn"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="-9dip"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="20dp"
                android:minWidth="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dip"
                android:text="@string/settings" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

is wrong.

The Dev describe the fillViewport as follows:

```
Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport.
```

Try to delete it and test it. I have several scroolviews working like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android_layout_height="fill_parent"
<LinearLayout>
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android_layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android_layout_height="fill_parent"
<RelativeLayout>
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android_layout_height="fill_parent"

... code

Comment: Because I cant, my anti-virus is poping up every time i try to hit edit >.>

Comment: It is working for me with the relative layout, you can try it if you want, Ill contact you if I found a solution

Answer (score 0):

i had no choice but to write the layout again , this time i added RelativeLayout as child view of the scrollView. it works.